# How to convert string (time or date time) in timestamp and save in mongodb

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mongodb

I am accepting time as string from user like "10:00am" or if needed i can accept "2015-08-27 10:00am" from user.

Need to use rails function *Date("2015-08-27 10:00am")* to convert string in date and then needs to save in db?

I'm currently using

- ruby 2.2.2
- rails 4.1.4
- mongoid 4.0.0

Comment: Whilst it should be ( and is as the nice person has answered for you ) very simple to parse a respectfully valid date "string" into a timestamp value, I would still strongly advise you actually store as a [BSON Date](http://docs.mongodb.org/master/reference/bson-types/#date) instead. As quoted in documentation *"is a 64-bit integer that represents the number of milliseconds since the Unix epoch"* which means that this internally will take up the same storage space as a numeric timestamp will, but has the added advatage of being typed as a Date. As such your language can also treat it as a date

Comment: @BlakesSeven so need to pass ISODate() instead of Time.parse()?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you have input `2015-08-27 10:00am` you can [parse](http://apidock.com/ruby/Time/parse/class) like this:

```
time = Time.parse '2015-08-27 10:00am'
```

**Mongoid**

In case you use [Mongoid](http://mongoid.com), [create your model](http://docs.mongodb.org/ecosystem/tutorial/ruby-mongoid-tutorial/#documents) and assign it to respective field. For example:

```
user = User.create(username: 'dimakura', talk_time: time)
```

**Ruby Driver**

In case you use [Ruby Driver](http://docs.mongodb.org/ecosystem/tutorial/ruby-driver-), use the following code:

```
client = Mongo::Client.new([ '127.0.0.1:27017' ], :database => 'mydb')
result = client[:users].insert_one({ username: 'dimakura', talk_time: time })
```